# Swap extact eth with fees

Tags: transactions, uniswap

I want to buy a new token at launch, its on ethereum erc20, in uniswap v2 contract i select write contract,  section 11 swap exact eth, then in the path section do I use the ethereum address from my wallet OR the ethereum contract address followed by the new token address???
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

path variable is token trading path , so it have to be token address.

Comment: Thank-you, so will this be erc20 dress or weth address

Comment: if you swap from ETH to erc20, then path[0] = WETH, path[1] = ERC20TokenAddress

Comment: Thanks again, so in my wallet I have etherium,  do I need to swap it to weth?

Comment: nope, u dont have to. When you trade in dex, it will wrap it for you.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect, do I need to pre-approve any thing in trust wallet to allow for high gas fees?

Comment: if you are swapping from ETH to ERC20 , then you dont need to do any approving.
if you are swapping from ERC20 to any other token, you will need to approve the uni router to transfer your ERC20 token.

Comment: Thanks again, 1 last thing, when I want to swap the token back to eth, do I just reverse the path??

Comment: There is a different method to call, https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol#L267 .